# Cause of seemingly random crashes in wininet.dll?

Tags: c++, crash, httprequest, wininet

I am getting crashes deep in wininet.dll. 
It crashed trying to read the zero memory location in `HTTP_REQUEST_HANDLE_OBJECT::ReleaseConnection`

Is this a bug in the actual DLL and not caused by improper usage?

> wininet!HTTP_REQUEST_HANDLE_OBJECT::ReleaseConnection+0x60
>   wininet!HTTP_REQUEST_HANDLE_OBJECT::CloseConnection+0x84
>   wininet!HTTP_REQUEST_HANDLE_OBJECT::ReadData_Fsm+0x5e8
>   wininet!CFsm_ReadData::RunSM+0x2e
>   wininet!CFsm::Run+0x39
>   wininet!DoFsm+0x25
>   wininet!HTTP_REQUEST_HANDLE_OBJECT::ReadData+0x38
>   wininet!HTTP_REQUEST_HANDLE_OBJECT::HttpReadData_Fsm+0x43
>   wininet!CFsm_HttpReadData::RunSM+0x2e
>   wininet!CFsm::Run+0x39
>   wininet!DoFsm+0x25
>   wininet!HttpReadData+0x67
>   wininet!ReadFile_Fsm+0x2d
>   wininet!CFsm_ReadFile::RunSM+0x2b
>   wininet!CFsm::Run+0x39
>   wininet!DoFsm+0x25
>   wininet!InternetReadFile+0x3ca

The context is I am trying to download a file. I am calling

InternetReadFile (hFile, lpBuffer, dwNumberOfBytesToRead, lpdwNumberOfBytesRead);

The hFile HINTERNET handle seems fine (value is 0x00cc0024 which seems legit) the dwNumberOfBytesToRead is 20000.

My buffer size is 131000 which is fine too.

The thing is my code works 99.9999% of the time!

Comment: You're probably passing it invalid data. What call from your program causes the crash? Please paste the call and the relevant surrounding code.

Comment: You'll need to provide *much* more context, i.e. an example of how you're calling into WinInet that triggers the error **and** the O/S and service pack level you're testing on. Given that it's a core part of the Windows OS, it's extremley likely the fault lies with you (though there's always a chance you've found an as yet unknown bug in Windows =)

Comment: I am trying to download a file. I am calling
InternetReadFile (hFile, lpBuffer, dwNumberOfBytesToRead, lpdwNumberOfBytesRead);

The hFile HINTERNET handle seems fine (value is 0x00cc0024 which seems legit) the dwNumberOfBytesToRead is 20000.

Comment: Hans Im not so sure, if it was heap courruption, it seems unlikely it would be reading memory location 0. Heap corruptions usually read a random memory location. Reading 0 seems more like your code shooting itself in the foot.

Answer (score 0):

Check use of `lpdwNumberOfBytesRead`.  It should be either

```
DWORD *lpdwNumberOfBytesRead = &someDWORDsomewhere;
InternetReadFile (..., lpdwNumberOfBytesRead);
```

or

```
DWORD NumBytes
InternetReadFile (..., &NumBytes);
```

I have a feeling you are doing the first method without setting the pointer variable somewhere valid.

Comment: Im doing the second method, the thing is my code works 99.9999% of the time! Thanks for the pointer though.

Comment: If you want a speedy and correct answer, please post the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem was in calling InternetCloseHandle in other threads with an already closed handle. Normally this just returns ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE but in some circumstances makes wininet crash either in InternetCloseHandle or as in this case.